# SSO login with Azure AD using React JS

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, msal-react

I'm facing an issue with Cross-origin token redemption while developing a Single-Page Application (SPA). I'm getting the following error:

"Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type. Request origin: 'http://localhost:3000'."

My React JS App code

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { config } from './Config';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this. state = {
      error: null,
      isAuthenticated: false,
      user:{}
    }
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.publicClientApplication = new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: config.appId,
        redirectUri: config.redirectUri,
        authority: config.authority
      }
    })
  }
  async login() {
    try {
      await this.publicClientApplication.loginPopup({
        scopes: config.scopes,
        prompt: "select_account"
      });
      this.setState({isAuthenticated:true})
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState({
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: {},
        error: err
      })
    }
  }

  logout() {
    this.publicClientApplication.logout()
  }

  
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
        </a>
          {this.state.isAuthenticated ? <p>Learn React </p>:
          
          <p><button onClick={() => this.login()}>Login In</button></p> }
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
}



export default App;
```

config.js

```
export const config = {
    appId:My_APP_ID,
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000",
    scopes: [
        'user.read'
    ],
    authority:"https://login.microsoftonline.com/My_APP_TENT_ID"
}
```

`

after login enter username password token api show 400 bad request

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SgRD.png)

Please suggest me what's wrong above code. If did any mistake suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The configuration for your client is wrong on your azure dashboard. You probably have selected a public web application or something, you need to select SPA

Comment: @AdamJenkins can you please suggest where is the location in azure dashboard. Because I am little confuse. If you provide me proper path or location it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an application, it's under redirect URI, I'm looking to see where I can find it for an existing application

[image]

You can also edit your manifest file for your application directly by adding redirect URIs:

[image]

```
    "replyUrlsWithType": [
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "type": "Spa"
        },
        ...other urls
    ],
```